# Angular: Dynamically render a component based on its name

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application that retrieves from the database a set of Metrics the user has access to. Each one of those Metrics is rendered as a tab, and has a corresponding component in my Angular App. I would like to be able to render the corresponding component inside the Tab, using its name or some other identifier. So, my code looks like this:

```
<tabset #metricTabs>
    <tab *ngFor="let metric of campaign.metrics"
        [id]="metric.id"
        [heading]="metric.name"
        (select)="getMetricData(metric.id)"
        [active]="hasOnlyOneMetric">
        HERE, I WOULD LIKE TO BE ABLE TO RENDER 
        THE COMPONENT THAT HAS THE NAME CONTAINED
        IN 'metric.componentName', FOR INSTANCE
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Examples of my metrics are **MonthlySummary** and **WeeklyAverage**. So, in my app, I have a component called **monthly-summary.component.ts**, and another one called **weekly-average.component.ts** (each one with its corresponding htmls and css).
Is there a way to render that component based on its name? So, instead of using **<app-monthly-summary>** in my markup, I would like to take the name associated to the metric object I use to render the tabs (metric.componentName is 'MonthlySummary', for example), and render it using that string.

Is that possible? Furthermore, how would I pass parameters to that component?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader ? A simpler technique would just be to add a `<router-outlet>` and define the components and path names in the route. Then define the path to the route dynamically in your code above.

Comment: Either use routing or perhaps a creative ngIf construction, tho the latter would be suboptimal.